# Volley NetworkImage in ArrayAdapter -> load Drawable-Res conditionally

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using volleys **NetworkImageView** to load image´s in an **ArrayAdapter**.

For some Items in my Adapter i want to use a **Drawable resource instead**.

Unfortunally setting the ImageResource doesnt seem to have an effect on NetworkImage.

```
    networkImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.mydrawable); // no effect
```

I tryed working without NetworkImageView using an ImageLoaders get() method providing an interface. Unfortunally the view recycling didnt work out anymore and image downloads overrode already recycled and reused views.

```
    ImageLoader.ImageListener listener = 
    ImageLoader.getImageListener(image, R.drawable.loading, R.drawable.error);
    ImageCacheManager.getImageLoader().get(url,listener);
    // Override´s recycled views image
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only want to show drawable and not load any image at all for specific item, this is quite easy:

```
public void bind(Item item) {
  if (item.shouldDisplayDrawable()) {
    imageView.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.my_drawable); // show your drawable
    imageView.setImageUrl(null, app.getImageLoader()); // and if url == null, Volley will not load any image to replace Default 
  } else {
    imageView.setImageUrl(item.getImageUrl(), app.getImageLoader()); // load image from url
  } 
}
```

I tried this in my Adapter, recycling works without any issues. And you can continue using

```
imageView.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.icon_image_default);
imageView.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.icon_image_error);
```

on `imageView` you download from url, it will display correct drawable while loading and on error.

Comment: Thx, i missed out in the possiblility to pass null.

Comment: Any ideas if you want to replace it with a drawable instead of a blank screen?

Comment: @e3matheus, what do you mean "instead of blank screen"?
To display placeholder while actually loading image from network use `imageView.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.icon_image_default);`
To display placeholder if error occurres use `imageView.setErrorImageResId(R.drawable.icon_image_error);`

Comment: I have a NetworkImageView that can receive a null url value. If I assign the network image view a null url, volley leaves a blank screen. I want to load a "no image found" drawable instead.

The error drawable for some reason is not being used if I pass a url that doesn't exist. I get an Exception

Comment: @e3matheus, so following does not work for your case?
`imageView.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.no_image_found);
 imageView.setImageUrl(null, app.getImageLoader());`

Comment: No, I get a blank screen.